# DataSet and how to input and update

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, sql-insert

I'm trying to use a dataset to insert a new row into my database table once a button is clicked.

I have created the table in the SQL database, created a dataset via the `add new data source option` and put the insert query into the `StudentDetails` table.

I want a method to execute that inserts the data typed when the button is clicked.

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SummerSchoolDataSetTableAdapters.StudentDetailsTableAdapter studentDetailsTableAdapter =
new SummerSchoolDataSetTableAdapters.StudentDetailsTableAdapter();
        studentDetailsTableAdapter.Insert();
    }
```

I do not know what to put in the brackets after insert.

Comment: `Sorry if this is a poorly constructed post...` Reading [ask] and taking the [tour] and perhaps visiting the [help] means (almost) never having to apologize for not knowing how things work on SO.

Comment: Ah cheers, my bad mate. I'll make sure to look at all them for next time. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: What does the DB table look like?  How about the object within .NET.  It's a datatable, I assume?  Can you add these to your question, along with where the data is stored within the UI.